# Is there a way to add features to Azure Resource Groups?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

When trying to deploy an app through AZ cli, I run into the following message:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.1:deploy (default-cli) on project rest: Requested feature is not available in resource group myresourcegroup. Please try using a different resource group or
create a new one.: OnError while emitting onNext value: retrofit2.Response.class -> [Help 1]`

I know the message sort of implies that the only way to remedy this is a separate resource group, but I wanted to check that there is no possible way to just add features to an existing resource group I'm trying to use (`myresourcegroup` in this case)?

Comment: what is the command you are running?

Comment: `mvn azure-webapp:deploy` @silent, my pom just references an existing resource group which apparently doesnt have the features for azure webapp?